# Excel - format cells in certain rows and with certain values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

My problem is very specific and I didn't find the answer to it yet (neither on google nor here), so I'll just ask.

I have an Excel sheet where the third column contains text that is either "Contribution" or "Donation" or something else and the cells in columns 4+ contain numbers if it's either of the two.

Example:

```
 ┌───┬───┬──────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
 │...│...│ Contribution │ 120  │ 800  │ 1200 │
 ├───┼───┼──────────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
 │...│...│ Donation     │ 30   │ 20   │ 200  │
 ├───┼───┼──────────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
 │...│...│ Activity     │ yes  │ no   │ yes  │
 ├───┼───┼──────────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
 │...│...│ Donation     │ 50   │ 100  │ 18   │
 ├───┼───┼──────────────┼──────┼──────┼──────┤
 │...│...│ Contribution │ 80   │ 2500 │ 1800 │
 └───┴───┴──────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

I want to add additional formatting that highlights certain cells.

- If the row contains "Contribution" and the cell's value is >= 1000
- If the row contains "Donation" and the cell's value is >= 50

But **not** if the row contains "Contribution" and the cell's value is >= 50 (& < 1000). So in my example above, the highlighted cells would be these:

```
                                      ┌──────┐
  ... ...  Contribution   120    800  │ 1200 │
                                      ├──────┤
  ... ...  Donation       30     20   │ 200  │
                                      └──────┘
  ... ...  Activity       yes    no     yes
                        ┌──────┬──────┐
  ... ...  Donation     │ 50   │ 100  │ 18
                        └──────┼──────┼──────┐
  ... ...  Contribution   80   │ 2500 │ 1800 │
                               └──────┴──────┘
```

All I have found so far are ways to either highlight rows containing certain text-strings **or** highlight cells with a certain value but no combination of the two... is it possible?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit:**
As an attempt to make it easier to follow:
[image: Worksheet 1 (excerpt)]

On the screenshot above I want to highlight values >= 1000 in columns 4~n of rows 3,6,9,12,... and values >= 50 in columns 4~n of rows 4,7,10,13,... for an infinite number of rows and columns. So on the screenshot row 4 col 4 should be green as well.

If there is a way to check values in rows that are (3n) or (3n+1) instead of checking for "Contribution" or "Donation" that would work in this scenario, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(A1="Contribution",IF(B1>=1000,true,false),IF(B1>=50,true,false))
```

Paste this in additional cells of the sheet.
Based on true/false you could highlight the cells. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow... where would I insert this formula and how can it apply to every cell in the row that meets the condition if there are several columns after "Contribution"?

Comment: You could paste this formula in one cell and then drag to the complete range.

Comment: In regards to the screenshot I added to my original question, where would you paste that formula? The table extends to the right and bottom by an unspecified number of cells, so I can't paste it next to or under the table and of course I can't paste it in the cells that are supposed to be updated with the numbers... could you please elaborate a tiny bit more on it...?

Comment: Actually nevermind. Using your formula/suggestion as a basis I was able to get the result that I wanted. Just note that there is an "IF(" missing before your "B1>=50" case.

Comment: My bad. Its a very bad type on code.. anyway hope this idea helped you